# What does "mu" mean as an interjection?

Tags: interjections

I'm reading the *Dragon Ball* manga and characters keep sort of stammering "mu-mu-mu" at various moments, for example below. What does this mean?

[image]

Comment: Pronounce it like an upset 'Mmm'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is む sometimes pronounced more like ん?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11613/is-%e3%82%80-sometimes-pronounced-more-like-%e3%82%93)

Comment: Kind of related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/47235/7810

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I love this comic too. Mu mu mu expresses frustration in a calm way.

Comment: You should cite a dictionary entry or something to support your answer.

Comment: I think this expression is too casual to be on list of dictionaries. But as a native speaker of Japanese and a fan of this comic I think this phrase conveys such meaning.

Comment: We westerners tend to be agitated when experiencing frustration.